# Android fragment addToBackStack not working with Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I had Created a Home activity which includes a Navigation Drawer onclick with fragment. I had included  `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();` with the fragment transaction code. But it doesn't go back to previous page,instead it is closing the app.

In My `MainActivity`

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    RelativeLayout mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

  if (id == R.id.nav_project) {
        ProjectFragment fragment = new ProjectFragment();
        mainLayout.removeAllViews();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainlayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

My Default `Fragment`

```
public class ProjectFragment extends Fragment {

       @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_project, container, false);

            return v;
        }



}
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "But it doesn't response."? Does the app exit to Home when you hit the Back key?

Comment: it doesn't go back to previous page,instead it is closing the app.

Comment: Thanks Rubin for your text modification. Maybe you will get more attention, you got mine, hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response, it helps. Basically you need to **add a fragment to the stack**.

Instead of using `replace`(), use the `add` method of `fragmentTransaction`. This will give you the desired effect.

Easy sample: `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainlayout, fragment);`

Comment: thank u very much sir/ But it works only on one transition .

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu, Are you crashing on the other fragment transition? I thought you were.

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu,  You may post another issue on this app crash. If you do, let me know in this thread. On the new issue, you can mention about this post if it makes sense and helpful.

Comment: Sir i had created another question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33492126/commit-already-called-error-in-android-addtobackstack-for-fragment