# "commit already called" error in android addToBackStack for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I had Created a Home activity which includes a Navigation Drawer onclick with fragment. I had included  `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();` with the fragment transaction code to go back to previous page.

My Desired requirement was `NavigationDrawer-->Fragment1-->Fragment2--> On BackButtonPress-->Fragment1(On BackButton Pressed)-->MainActivity.`

But,Now i am only able to move to `Fragment1`,But cant move to `Fragment2`.
It shows an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called`

In My MainActivity

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    RelativeLayout mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

  if (id == R.id.nav_project) {
        ProjectFragment fragment = new ProjectFragment();
        mainLayout.removeAllViews();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainlayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();

    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

My First Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    Button signin,login;
    ImageView logo;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login,container,false);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        final RelativeLayout mainLayout=(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        signin=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SignUpFragment fragment = new SignUpFragment();
                mainLayout.removeAllViews();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainlayout, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        login=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginEnterFragment fragment = new LoginEnterFragment();
                mainLayout.removeAllViews();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainlayout, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        logo=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        return v;
    }

}
```

My third Fragment

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class LoginEnterFragment extends Fragment {

    public LoginEnterFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_enter, container, false);
    }


}
```

My Logcat

```
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.rubin, PID: 676
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:621)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.LoginFragment$2.onClick(LoginFragment.java:53)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-01 23:44:17.237 676-676/com.example.rubin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: commit already called

Because calling `commit()` method two time in `LoginFragment` Fragment on `signin` and `login` Button click :

```
fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

lines causing issue.

Use `addToBackStack` method as:

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: yes i did it and error resolved, but now when i an pressing back button, the screen becomes white.

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu: when using simply `fragmentTransaction.commit();` then?

Comment: When i am using fragmentTransaction.commit(); app will close when i press back button.. then i tried with  fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit(); ,then i got IllegalStateException. then i removed fragmentTransaction.commit(); ,now Back button is working ,But my View is blank(filled with White color).

Comment: Is that due to mainLayout.removeAllViews();

Comment: i removed mainLayout.removeAllViews(); from code. Now back button is working perfectly. But every new fragment is overlapping to previous page.

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu: ohhh dude !!! one Fragment(ProjectFragment) is already in Fragment container so no need to use add method again just use `replace` instead of `add`

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu: in `LoginFragment ` Fragment use `replace` instead of `add` on both signin and login Button click

Comment: Yes Sir,it worked for fragment1 and fragment2. But when i go back to main Activity. Still the view is empty.

Comment: i used replace in main activity too. but still it doesnt work.

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu :  not need to  use `replace` in main Activity use add method and also try to use `fragmentTransaction.commit();` instead of `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Comment: Sir i will post it as a new question because i should add the whole code from my project. Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: Sir pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493612/tablayout-in-mainactivty-is-not-showing-when-using-addtobackstack-from-a-fragm